# jquery post pass multiple arguments to the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

This might be a stupid question but I can't figure out a way to pass multiple arguments to the function when I do jquery post.

I have something like this

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url("scores")/getScore/?>/", showScore);
```

I have a php function getScore that echos json_encode data and passes it to the javascript function showScore.

Ideally what I want to do would be something like this:

```
var argument1 = 100;

$.post("<?php echo site_url("scores")/getScore/?>/", showScore(json_encoded_data_from_getScore, argument1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use parameters in your case.
In the example above variable `argument1` will be visible inside of `showScore(json_encoded_data_from_getScore)` because of it will be closured to this function.
If you need parameter you should wrap your function call to smth like this

```
var argument1 = 100;
var argument1 = 'foo bar';

$.post("<?php echo site_url("scores")/getScore/?>/", 
    function(theArgument1, theArgument2) {
         // (2) arguments are in closure
         return function(data) { // (3) this functions will be returned from self-called function 
                                 // and then called with parameter 'data' as success handler 
             showScore.call(this, data, theArgument1, theArgument2); // (4) it's time to invoke 
                                                                     // showScore with
                                                                     // required parameters 
         }
    }(argument1, argument2) // (1) this function calls itself to create closure
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! The function showScore is actually not in the same closure as the variable but you're code example seems to work! Thanks!